# How to run a custom docker image testContainer

Tags: scala, integration-testing, testcontainers

I have gone thru' multiple blogs and official documentation but couldn't resolve my issue. I am using **testContainers-scala version 0.38.1** and **scala version 2.11**.

I am trying to create a simple test using testContainer-scala as below:

```
class MyServiceITSpec extends AnyFlatSpec with ForAllTestContainer {
  override val container = GenericContainer(dockerImage="my-service",
    exposedPorts = Seq(8080),
    env=(HashMap[String, String]("PARAM1" -> "value1", "PARAM2" -> "value2", "PARAM3" -> "value3")),
    waitStrategy = Wait.forHttp("/")
  )

  "GenericContainer" should "start my service and say Hello! Wassupp" in {
    assert(Source.fromInputStream(
      new URL(s"http://${container.containerIpAddress}:${container.mappedPort(8080)}/").openConnection().getInputStream
    ).mkString.contains("Hello! Wassupp"))
  }
}
```

On the basis of the above snippet, my understanding is this (please correct if wrong):

1. Port 8155 is exposed by the docker container and a random host port against the same would be assigned.
2. We can get that assigned port as container.mappedPort

Here I am trying to assert that **http:// localhost:mappedPort/** return **Hello! Wassupp**.

But, I get the below error:

```
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Could not create/start container
  at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:498)
  at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:325)
  at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:81)
  ... 18 more
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Timed out waiting for URL to be accessible (http://localhost:32869/ should return HTTP 200)
  at org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.HttpWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(HttpWaitStrategy.java:214)
  at org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.AbstractWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(AbstractWaitStrategy.java:35)
  at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.waitUntilContainerStarted(GenericContainer.java:890)
  at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:441)
  ... 20 more
```

The same image runs just fine with:

```
docker run -p 8081:8080 -e PARAM1=value1 -e PARAM2=value2 -e PARAM3=VALUE3 my-service
```

Comment: Are you sure that you application returns http code 200?

waitStrategy = Wait.forHttp("/") implies that an http response should be returned.

Comment: Yes, it does. However, I found that the root of this problem is missing Headers. Adding the answer below for reference for anyone who may run into similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after juggling with the errors, I found my issue. It is to do with the required Request Headers missing from the request. I am adding the reference code for anyone who runs into similar issue.

```
import com.dimafeng.testcontainers.{ForAllTestContainer, GenericContainer}
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec
import org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.Wait

import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap
import scalaj.http.Http



    class MyServiceITSpec extends AnyFlatSpec with ForAllTestContainer {
      override val container = GenericContainer(dockerImage="my-service-img:tag12345",
        exposedPorts = Seq(8080),
        env=(HashMap[String, String]("PARAM1" -> "value1", "PARAM2" -> "value2")),
        waitStrategy = Wait.forHttp("/") // or "/health" based on ur implementation 
      )
    
      "My Service" should "successfully fetch the msg" in {
        assert(Http(s"http://${container.containerIpAddress}:${container.mappedPort(8080)}/products/product1")
          .header("HEADER1", "value1")
          .header("HEADER2", "value2")
          .asString.code==200)
      }
    
    }
```

Some explanations that I found after a lot of reading:

1. You give the port number that your docker application exposes as **exposedPorts**.
2. TestContainers then does a mapping of this port against a random port (this is by design to avoid port number conflicts). If you were to run this docker image directly on your machine you would write:

**`docker run -p 8081:8080 -e PARAM1=value1 -e PARAM2=value2 my-service-img:tag12345`**

Here, your **exposed port is 8080** and the **mapped port is 8081**.

1. TestContainers runs the docker image by exposing the port 8080 and then mapping it against a random port. The mapped port can be **container.mappedPort()**.
2. Another important thing to notice is the wait strategy. This tells the code to wait unless the **`/`** endpoint gets up. This is kind of a health check that your application exposes. You can have a better endpoint for the same - like **`/health`**. By default, it waits for **60 seconds** for this endpoint to become active. Post that it would anyway run the tests and if the application has not started by then, it would cause an error. I am not sure how to override the default timeout but I think there should be a way to do that.
3. Lastly, I am using **`scalaj.http.Http`** to make a HTTP request(it is a pretty easy one to use - you can ).